# Luna HSM key cache

Tags: hsm

I'm working with a Luna SA HSM through PKCS11 and i have the following scenario: I have created a master key pair for key wrapping and i want to bring a key wrapped with the master public key into the HSM. So, i search for the master private key and then use it to unwrap the wrapped key. I then use the unwrapped key for a decryption process. After that, i destroy the unwrapped key.

My question is this: If after destroying the unwrapped key i unwrapped it again, will the HSM treat it as a new key or it has some internal mechanism to cache keys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be a new key from the HSM point of view and the handle you'll get will be different too.

So the answer is 'no', the HSM won't cache the unwrapped key.

What you can do, is keep the handle without destroying it, but from the looks of it, you do want to destroy it.